# How to find string consisting of digit and symbol, like "2. "(space after dot) in PHP?

Tags: php

How do you break the string into array starting at its listing number, for example "2. " in the string.

Input:
`1. new zealand 0.909991233 2. france and it territories 0.114444444 3. united states 0.99991119991 and so on`

Output:

```
array (
   "1. new zealand 0.909991233",
   "2. france and it territories 0.114444444",
   "3. united states 0.99991119991"
)
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. I know its not very easy;)

Comment: [Close enough?](http://3v4l.org/hgIol)

Comment: Thx for responses! Now I have a direction where to go!. I am testing on the data set and it seems the regex after 10th listing starts to break the numbers it shouldn't. I'll do more testing and will update the post. Thx again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
$str = "1. new zealand 0.909991233 2. france and it territories 0.114444444 3. united states 0.99991119991";

$pattern = '/(\d+\.\s)/i';
$replacement = '; $1';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
$arr = explode('; ', $str);

echo implode("<br>", $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too bad, one line really that does the work.

```
<?php
// Input
$input = "1. new zealand 0.909991233 2. france and it territories 0.114444444 3. united states 0.99991119991";

// Split the input
$ex = preg_split( "#(?=\d+\.\s+)#", $input);

// (Optional) Lose the empty result
unset( $ex[0] );

// Output
var_dump( $ex );
```

http://codepad.org/wxtmbU15

Comment: @jogesh_pi Just how splitting works when the first character is split. It sends everything before the deliminator (here, nothing) as the first segment. I've updated my post to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172546/how-to-find-string-consisting-of-digit-and-symbol-like-2-space-after-dot-i?noredirect=1#comment28364550_19172546):

In case of two or more digits index, you can be a little more aggressive in RegExp:

```
array_map("trim",preg_split('#(?=\W[0-9]+\.\s+)#',"1. new zealand 0.909991233 22. france and it territories 0.114444444 333. united states 0.99991119991 and so on"))
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. new zealand 0.909991233
    [1] => 22. france and it territories 0.114444444
    [2] => 333. united states 0.99991119991 and so on
)
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/kGpqP)